# Im trying to load phtml file via xml for added refund tab in magento?

Tags: php, xml, magento

Im trying to load an file sales/guest/form.phtml  for added tab left navigation tab on customer my account, via customer.xml but didn't kindly help me.
Refund

Comment: can you elaborate more ? what have you done so far

Comment: i added refund tab in left side and want to load page sales/guest/form.phtml page via xml but not get it?

Comment: you mean you added a new link in my account left navigation and now on its click you want to open sales/guest/form.phtml in the right column ?

Comment: yes but not open kindly help me pls

Comment: new link mean i want refund tab and i added through customer.xml

Comment: wait for 10 mins, although i cannot tell you complete ans for this, but i am sure you will do it youself after reading the steps.

Answer (score 0):

I have done somewhat similar in my old project. here is what i do :

Added a new link in My Account section from customers.xml i.e

```
<action method="addLink" translate="label" module="preorder"><name>Previous_Orders</name><path>preorder/index/</path><label>Previous Orders</label></action>
```

In your case you can use an already running module instead of preorder and change the name in above action.

In module/contollers/IndexController.php add a view as follows :

```
public function viewAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();     
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
```

Add preorder/preorder.phtml template folder in your theme template folder.

in your theme layout folder add preorder.xml as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
    </default>
    <preorder_index_index>
        <label>Customer My Account Previous Orders</label>
        <update handle="customer_account"/>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="preorder/preorder" name="preorder" template="preorder/preorder.phtml" />

        </reference>
    </preorder_index_index>
</layout>
```

Hope you ot the idea, what we have done is created a new module which loads the template on index action, you cn change the name of module "preorder" and also the action "index" while working on this.

I was very brief while writing this, Hope this helps you in someway.

Comment: module/contollers/IndexController.php file not in my project what do i do?

Comment: by module i mean your modulename, for ex in my case app/code/local/Hue/Preorder/controllers/IndexController.php

Comment: Thanks for help me this is my code runing. public function refundAction()
{

$this->loadLayout();
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setTitle($this->__('Refund'));
$this->renderLayout();
}